# accessing u-boot and kernel debug console on baltos ir2110

Tags: linux, console, serial-port

I am using baltos ir 2110 and creating a custom image for it. I was able to access it via ssh with the standard bolts Debian image. But with my custom image, it is not coming in the network ( in conclusion it is not booting ). I want to access the bootloader cli and check kernel logs to find the error but I don't know how to access it.
I have tried to connect the RS 232 serial port to my computer but no logs are available on that port. Is there any other debug port that I can access to see the serial console on baltos?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is a serial console to baltos ir 2110. You can access it using a tty-USB cable which will give you access to u boot terminal.